# what is the Maximum Number of replica download possible from download.geofabrik.de?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I am trying to update more than 5 months of Nominatim europe data from download.geofabrik.de. For 8 to 10 days its works fine but after that it showing error 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Is there any restriction in downloading replication from download.geofabrik.de server per IP?

Comment: Have you asked Geofabrik?

Comment: Mailed but i didn't get any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downloading three months of updates and applying them will probably
take *longer* than downloading the full data file and importing it afresh!

The server will let you download about 30 files a day so you would have
to space your downloads a bit.

Thank you Frederik Ramm